# How to delete an instantiated object Python?

Tags: python, variables, object

I am relatively new to object oriented programming and I cannot figure out how to delete an instantiated object in Python.

```py
if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True or self.hit_paddle2(pos) == True:
    bar = bar + 1
if bar == 1:
    global barbox1
    barbox1 = barfill(canvas)
    barbox1.canvas.move(barbox1.id, 253, 367)
if bar == 2:
    global barbox2
    barbox2 = barfill(canvas)
    barbox2.canvas.move(barbox5.id, 413, 367)
    bar = 0
    time.sleep(0.2)
    barbox1 = None
    barbox2 = None
```

That is the code, the main thing I was trying in order to delete the objects was `barbox1 = None`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Are you using `pygame` or something similar? The library probably provides a way to remove the objects from the display. Assigning `None` to those variables may or may not do anything because you are just removing a reference, but the library could have other references to those objects that keep them alive.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by getting rid of `barbox1`?

Comment: To my understanding, if you set `barbox1 = None`, as `barbox1` is the only reference to the object, you've already deleted the object and released the memory taken by the object, no need to worry about the variable name itself.

Answer (score 75):

`object.__del__(self)` is called when the instance is about to be destroyed.

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __del__(self):
...         print "deleted"
... 
>>> test = Test()
>>> del test
deleted
```

Object is not deleted unless all of its references are removed(As quoted by ethan)

Also, From Python official doc reference:

> `del x` doesn’t directly call `x.__del__()` — the former decrements the
> reference count for `x` by one, and the latter is only called when `x`‘s
> reference count reaches zero

Comment: I've tried if you directly set `test = None`, the `__del__` function will be called too.

Answer (score 30):

What do you mean by `delete`?  In Python, removing a reference (or a name) can be done with the `del` keyword, but if there are other names to the same object that object will not be deleted.

```
--> test = 3
--> print(test)
3
--> del test
--> print(test)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

compared to:

```
--> test = 5
--> other is test  # check that both name refer to the exact same object
True
--> del test       # gets rid of test, but the object is still referenced by other
--> print(other)
5
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that there *is no way* to reliably delete an object in python?  Would it be possible, for instance, to obtain all of the references to an object and `del` them into oblivion?

Comment: @Scott: You might, with enough effort, be able to find all the references to an object -- but if any of those references are in namespaces (such as function locals) that you cannot access you won't be able to `del` them.

Comment: @Him That's correct, there is no way. Fortunately, because what do you think should happen if then some code that has a reference tries to access the object?  That would be the equivalent of a dangling pointer in C, C++, and similar languages.  This class of errors is prevented by not giving the programmer the means to delete an object that is in use somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

Python manages the memory with the concept called **Reference counting**

What does it mean?

When an object is created, a dedicated memory to store the object gets created and the address of the memory is returned. We basically store the address in the variable.

Python tracks the number of variables that has the object address stored,  once all of the variables are removed/changed then python actually removes the memory allocated for the object.

Assume we have a class called `Treasure`

```
class Treasure:
    def __del__(self):
        print("Treasure is gone")

print("John creates a treasure and he know the location of it (count is 1)")
john = Treasure()

print("John shares the treasure location with Stark (count is 2)")
stark = john

print("Stark shares the treasure location with Chris (count is 3)")
chris = stark

print("John dies (count is 2)")
del john

print("Stark dies (count is 1)")
del stark

print("Chris dies (count is 0)")
del chris
```

**Output**

```
John creates a treasure and he know the location of it (count is 1)
John shares the treasure location with Stark (count is 2)
Stark shares the treasure location with Chris (count is 3)
John dies (count is 2)
Stark dies (count is 1)
Chris dies (count is 0)
Treasure is gone
```

**Treasure is gone** is printed only once after Chris dies, that is because when John died Stark & Chris knew the location and when Stark died Chris knew the location but when Chris died there is no one left who knows the location of the treasure.

the method `__del__` will be called only when the last reference is deleted

You can get the current number of references to an object using `getrefcount` from `sys`
**Example**

```
import sys

class A:
    """
    test class
    """

a = A()
b = a

print(sys.getrefcount(a))
```

**Output**

```
3
```

Usually the count will be one more due to the temporary reference in the `getrefcount` call

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what the (purpose of) the question is, since "*that doesn't seem to work.*" does not really describe the problem. Maybe there was some confusion about the difference between deleting an ***object*** or deleting a variable (i.e. a ***name***).

Anyway, what is not yet mentioned in all of the current other answers, is that `del` is **not** necessary to delete an object.
In fact, the user has no (direct) control over deletion of objects. This is done by the garbage collector, at some point in time, when there are no references to the object, or when the interpreter shuts down.

There are two ways of removing references to an object:

1. Using [`del`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) to *remove the binding of a name from the local or global namespace*:

   ```py
   del barbox1
   ```
2. Assigning another value to a name:

   ```py
   barbox1 = None
   ```

In the first case, the name (the "*variable*") `barbox1` is completely removed. Trying to access it after deleting it will result in a `NameError`, just like it was never assigned.
In the second case, the variable still exists, but does not refer to the *object* anymore.

In both cases, if there are no other references to the object, the object is removed by the garbage collector (as already pointed out in most of the other answers).

NB: The [`__del__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) method is not really relevant for deleting objects, except that it could be used to demonstrate when an object is deleted, although there are no hard guarantees when or even if the method is called. It can even be used to ***avoid*** deletion of the object. However, it certainly does not delete the object.

Answer (score 1):

An object in python is created by storing a memory address that points to the object. Example:

```
class SomeObject():
  def __init__(self, something, something_else):
    self.something = something
    self.something_else = something_else
  def some_method(self):
    return str(self.something)

a_variable_holding_a_memory_address = SomeObject(something=94, something_else=243)
a = a_variable_holding_a_memory_address
print(id(a) == id(a_variable_holding_a_memory_address))
```

Output:

```
True
```

If you don't know, `id()` returns the memory address of a variable in python.
Thus if you delete `a_variable_holding_a_memory_address`:

```
class SomeObject():
  def __init__(self, something, something_else):
    self.something = something
    self.something_else = something_else
  def some_method(self):
    return str(self.something)

a_variable_holding_a_memory_address = SomeObject(something=94, something_else=243)
a = a_variable_holding_a_memory_address
print(a_variable_holding_a_memory_address)
del a_variable_holding_a_memory_address
print(a)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7f80787ea940>
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7f80787ea940>
```

All that happened was a variable holding the memory address of an object (or a reference) was deleted, but the address itself was not as another reference to it exists.
Now look at this:

```
# In this example I use ctypes to print out the value at a memory address

import ctypes

class SomeObject():
  def __init__(self, something, something_else):
    self.something = something
    self.something_else = something_else
  def some_method(self):
    return str(self.something)

a_variable_holding_a_memory_address = SomeObject(something=94, something_else=243)
a = a_variable_holding_a_memory_address

# print out the value at the memory address that a_variable_holding_a_memory_address holds
object_id = id(a_variable_holding_a_memory_address)
print(ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value)

del a_variable_holding_a_memory_address

# now lets try it when only one of the references is deleted
print(ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value)

del a

# the same thing but when both of the references are deleted
print(ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7fbd04b5d3a0>
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7fbd04b5d3a0>
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7fbd04b5d3a0>
zsh: segmentation fault  python file.py
```

This segmentation fault happened because the program tried to reference an empty memory address.

This is one of the advantages of using a language of python versus c because it prevents this type of memory error unless you really try to make the program crash like in this example. This includes automatic garbage collection (a part of the python interpreter that frees up memory by emptying unused memory addresses).

But you see, when both of the references existed the memory address held an object.
When one is deleted the address is not because there still exists one reference to the address. That is the automatic garbage collector at work.
When both of them are deleted the address is too, thus the error. It should also be noted that simply assigning a different value to a variable like so:

```
a = "I now hold a str object"
```

Instead of:

```
del a
```

works too because the reference to the object is replaced with a reference to another object, thus one less reference.

This not only happens for user defined objects, but for very basic objects that come with python, often taken for granted, like `str` or `int` or `list` or `dict`, the list goes on. In the end, thats what variables hold in python, an object. Unless it holds a boolean like `True` or `False` or `None`. But those are objects too. Python docs for `None`:

> An object frequently used to represent the absence of a value, as when
> default arguments are not passed to a function. Assignments to None
> are illegal and raise a SyntaxError. None is the sole instance of the
> NoneType type.

Reference count:

The reference count to an object in python is the amount of variables holding a reference to the object. When that count reached zero, `__del__` is called of the object is called and it is destroyed (unless `__del__` does the following as outlined in the docs:

> It is possible (though not recommended!) for the **del**() method to
> postpone destruction of the instance by creating a new reference to
> it. This is called object resurrection. It is implementation-dependent
> whether **del**() is called a second time when a resurrected object is
> about to be destroyed; the current CPython implementation only calls
> it once.
> )

If you want a reference to an object that does not keep the object alive, there is a type of reference called a `weakref`:

```
import weakref

class SomeObject():
  def __init__(self, something, something_else):
    self.something = something
    self.something_else = something_else
  def some_method(self):
    return str(self.something)

reference = SomeObject('something', 'something_else')

print(reference)

weak_reference = weakref.ref(reference)

print(weak_reference)

del reference

print(weak_reference)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7f305b017880>
<weakref at 0x7f305ae7c630; to 'SomeObject' at 0x7f305b017880>
<weakref at 0x7f305ae7c630; dead>
```

The `weakref`, `weakreference` becomes a reference to nothing, a dead object.

Circling back the garbage collection, by using the `gc` built in library you can change some things about how the python garbage collector frees up memory.

One of those is disabling garbage collection:

```
import gc
# once again using ctypes
import ctypes
# disabling automatic garbage collection
gc.disable()

class SomeObject():
  def __init__(self, something, something_else):
    self.something = something
    self.something_else = something_else
  def some_method(self):
    return str(self.something)

a_variable_holding_a_memory_address = SomeObject(something=94, something_else=243)
a = a_variable_holding_a_memory_address

object_id = id(a_variable_holding_a_memory_address)
print(ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value)

del a_variable_holding_a_memory_address

print(ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value)

del a

print(ctypes.cast(object_id, ctypes.py_object).value)
```

Output:

```
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7f305ae6df10>
<__main__.SomeObject object at 0x7f305ae6df10>
<_ast.Interactive object at 0x7f305ae6df10>
```

The object is left even though there are no references to it. Usually the automatic garbage collector would free up the memory space used to store the object, but I disabled is with `gc.disable()`.

What is the `_ast.Interactive` object that is left?
First here is a simple overview of how python is interpreted by the c code it is written in:

1. Code is parsed into an array of tokens
2. The array of tokens is used to make an abstract syntax tree (`ast` as in `_ast`).
3. Byte code is generated from the abstract syntax tree
4. The byte code is run

So, after all the references to an object are removed and automatic garbage collection is disabled all that is left is the code of the object one level of abstraction above byte code.

Answer (score -3):

Simple answer: `del <variable>`

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```py
# Create variable
num = 5
num
# 5

# Delete it
del num

# Confirm it's gone
num
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

Comment: This only deletes the reference (i.e. the name); if other names are bound to the same object, that object still exists.

Comment: `del <variable>` deletes the object from the environment by removing the pointer to the object in memory (i.e. same way deletions work more generally, for example when someone right-clicks a file on a computer and selects 'delete', it removes the pointer but usually doesn't change what as written). Freeing unused memory might be done with [garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect). To clear memory with multiple pointers. I'd delete any variable(s) that are no longer needed and leave it to the language / garbage collection to sort out the freeing of memory.

Comment: you are incorrect.  The object is not deleted from the environment if other names in that environment still point to that name -- if they were, the OP would not be having the problem they describe.