# How do I delete the argument to a function

Tags: python

I am instantiating an object called  ray1 from a class.
I then instantiate an object called  refractor from another class
I then pass ray1 as an argument in a method belonging to the refractor object as such:

```
refracted_ray = refractor.propagate(ray1)
```

My question is, is there anything I can include in that function that will delete ray1 itself. In other words, can I delete the argument of a function within the function itself?

Comment: What do you mean "delete"? You mean like clean up the memory for that object?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete an instantiated object Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514631/how-to-delete-an-instantiated-object-python) - ***where*** you do it is not really important as long as you have a reference to the object...

Comment: you can call the object again with different argument like this: `refracted_ray = refractor.propagate(NEWRAY)`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Python uses reference counting. If there are any pointers left to an object, it won't get deleted. And by "pointer", I mean any variable or container pointing to it.

Comment: You cannot manually delete objects in Python.

Comment: Yes, as in clean up the memory for that object

Comment: `refractor.propagate` knows nothing about the name `ray1`, only that it has its own reference to the same object. It isn't that function's responsibility (or privilege) to fully delete the object, because it doesn't know that others may still be holding a reference for some purpose.

Comment: @joanis You can just say "reference" and leave pointers out of it.