# How to delete an instance of a class using a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I am looking for a way to create a method within a class that will delete that particular instance.

I know one way to do is by using del keyword but I want to make it user interaction based so that user can simply call the method and that instance will be deleted. How can I do that?

Comment: You cannot manually delete objects in Python. `del` unassigns variables. What you really need to do, most of the time, is remove the object from some data structure tracking your objects. That should be done through whatever the data structure is, not through the object itself.

Comment: You can store the class in a global list and then have it remove itself from that. Once it falls out of scope it will be garbage collected. I wouldn't recommend it, though. It's bad design.

Comment: This seems like a so-called XY problem, i.e. you're asking the wrong question. Better explain what you want to achieve instead of asking how to implement something that doesn't work. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Potentially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514631/how-to-delete-an-instantiated-object-python

Comment: Hi, so the problem is I want to delete an instance of the class. One way to do this is by using: a = Class() -- del a, but want to achieve the same functionality by implementing a method within the class for example a.method() deletes the instance of the class. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

@user2357112 mentioned how you cannot manually delete objects in Python, they are correct. Python objects are deleted when there are no more references to them. `del` removes the reference to an object and once that number of references goes down to zero, the garbage collector can reclaim the memory used by that object.

From [Python:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement)

> Deletion of a name **removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace**, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError exception will be raised...

`del` removes the reference to that instance of a class, if there are no other references to that instance elsewhere in your code, that reference count drops to zero, thereby allowing the garabage collector to reclaim the memory. The GC doesn't run immediately after every `del` statement, so once the GC runs again, it will reclaim your deleted instance.